# When I open the find prompt (Cmd+F mac), it doesn't focus on the dialog. How to change that?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is problematic as the focus is still on the editor window. I make accidental changes in the code.

[image]

Comment: Focuses properly on the find dialog for me...................

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Done as you said!